# Binary Files in C++, changing the content of raw data on an audio file

Tags: c++, file, file-io

I have never worked with binary files before. I opened an `.mp3` file using the mode `ios::binary`, read data from it, assigned `0` to each byte read and then rewrote them to another file opened in `ios::binary` mode. I opened the output file on a media player, it sounds corrupted but I can still hear the song. I want to know what happened physically.

How can I access/modify the raw data ( bytes ) of an audio ( video, images, ... ) using C++ ( to practice file encryption/decryption later )?

Here is my code:

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <fstream>
    #include <cstring>

    using namespace std;

    int main(){
        char buffer[256];
        ifstream inFile;
        inFile.open("Backstreet Boys - Incomplete.mp3",ios::binary);
        ofstream outFile;
        outFile.open("Output.mp3",ios::binary);
        while(!inFile.eof()){
            inFile.read(buffer,256);
            for(int i = 0; i<strlen(buffer); i++){
                buffer[i] = 0;
            }
            outFile.write(buffer,256);
        }
        inFile.close();
        outFile.close();
    }
```

Comment: Why is this tagged [tag:c], when you are using the [tag:c++] iostream library and namespaces?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you did has nothing to do with binary files or audio. You simply copied the file while zeroing some of the bytes. (The reason you didn't zero all of the bytes is because you use `i<strlen(buffer)`, which simply counts up to the first zero byte rather than reporting the size of the buffer. Also you modify the buffer which means `strlen(buffer)` will report the length as zero after you zero the first byte.)

So the exact change in audio you get is entirely dependent on the mp3 file format and the audio compression it uses. MP3 is not an audio format that can be directly manipulated in useful ways.

If you want to manipulate digital audio, you need to learn about how raw audio [is represented by computers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pulse-code_modulation).

It's actually not too difficult. For example, here's a program that writes out a raw audio file containing just a 400Hz tone.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <limits>

int main() {
  const double pi = 3.1415926535;

  double tone_frequency = 400.0;
  int samples_per_second = 44100;

  double output_duration_seconds = 5.0;

  int output_sample_count =
      static_cast<int>(output_duration_seconds * samples_per_second);

  std::ofstream out("signed-16-bit_mono-channel_44.1kHz-sample-rate.raw",
                    std::ios::binary);

  for (int sample_i = 0; sample_i < output_sample_count; ++sample_i) {
    double t = sample_i / static_cast<double>(samples_per_second);
    double sound_amplitude = std::sin(t * 2 * pi * tone_frequency);

    // encode amplitude as a 16-bit, signed integral value
    short sample_value =
        static_cast<short>(sound_amplitude * std::numeric_limits<short>::max());

    out.write(reinterpret_cast<char const *>(&sample_value),
              sizeof sample_value);
  }
}
```

To play the sound you need a program that can handle raw audio, such as [Audacity](http://web.audacityteam.org/). After running the program to generate the audio file, you can `File > Import > Raw data...`, to import the data for playing.

---

> How can I access/modify the raw data ( bytes ) of an audio ( video, images, ... ) using C++ ( to practice file encryption/decryption later )?

As pointed out earlier, the reason your existing code is not completely zeroing out the data is because you are using an incorrect buffer size: `strlen(buffer)`. The correct size is the number of bytes `read()` put into the buffer, which you can get with the function `gcount()`:

```
inFile.read(buffer,256);
int buffer_size = inFile.gcount();
for(int i = 0; i < buffer_size; i++){
    buffer[i] = 0;
}
outFile.write(buffer, buffer_size);
```

Note: if you were to step through your program using a debugger you probably would have pretty quickly seen the problem yourself when you noticed the inner loop executing less than you expected. Debuggers are a really handy tool to learn how to use.

---

I notice you're using `open()` and `close()` methods here. This is sort of pointless in this program. Just open the file in the constructor, and allow the file to be automatically closed when `inFile` and `outFile` go out of scope:

```
{
  ifstream inFile("Backstreet Boys - Incomplete.mp3",ios::binary);
  ofstream outFile("Output.mp3",ios::binary);

  // don't bother calling .close(), it happens automatically.
}
```

Comment: Not the first zero, just one byte. The reason is that after the first write `strlen` will return 0 on next call.